# How can I use self made cream of celery as a replacement for mushrooms in green bean casserole?

Tags: substitutions, sauce

I follow [Alton Brown's Green Bean Casserole](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/best-ever-green-bean-casserole-recipe-1950575) for the most part and have had great success making this recipe. My dad always complains about having mushrooms in the dish and he would have to pick them out. But this year I would like to try making without mushrooms.

My goal is to use another vegetable to replace the mushrooms when making the creamy sauce. From what I have heard you can use cream of celery soup but I would still like to make the cream myself. Can I use cut up celery as a replacement in Alton Brown's recipe? Do I need to alter cooking times? I think I would use 1 cup of chopped up celery.

Comment: The wide open question of what to substitute is too broad and would have to be closed: it allows any vegetable, and "tastes good" is more about personal taste so it doesn't really help. (From past experience, questions like that get a steady trickle of "I'd use this other thing!" answers forever.) The celery-specific question is fine for the site. So if you want to edit and so on still, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your original question, the revisions, and the comments, I have what may be an option for you. As noted in comments, you can use just about any vegetable you want.

To keep the flavor profile the same, make the creamy sauce as you usually do and then strain it well through a colander to remove the mushrooms. (You can also do this with celery.) By doing this you will have the flavor of mushrooms, celery, or whatever vegetable you choose in your dish.

The other option would be to purée your sauce.

Then, if you want a vegetable (of your choice) to add for texture, sautée them in a very small amount of butter to your desired consistency and add to your casserole.

If you don't feel the need for adding another vegetable, simply don't add any.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I like your idea of pureeing the mushrooms. This year I ended up making the sauce with mushrooms and then use tongs to take out the mushrooms when I am done with the sauce.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can substitute celery.

This segment of Alton Brown's recipe is actually making homemade cream of mushroom soup:

> Melt the butter in a 12-inch cast iron skillet set over medium-high
>   heat. Add the mushrooms, 1 teaspoon salt and pepper and cook, stirring
>   occasionally, until the mushrooms begin to give up some of their
>   liquid, approximately 4 to 5 minutes. Add the garlic and nutmeg and
>   continue to cook for another 1 to 2 minutes. Sprinkle the flour over
>   the mixture and stir to combine. Cook for 1 minute. Add the broth and
>   simmer for 1 minute. Decrease the heat to medium-low and add the
>   half-and-half. Cook until the mixture thickens, stirring occasionally,
>   approximately 6 to 8 minutes.

So instead of cooking mushrooms in the butter, cook celery, and you have created cream of *celery* soup. **How much celery and how long to cook it is largely a matter of taste** (do you like lots of crunchy celery, do you want it to be unobtrusive?) -- the important part is to keep the butter and flour ratio the same, since that makes the roux which thickens the "soup" that will form the creamy base of your casserole.

And you could also just leave out the mushrooms or celery :)